# What am I doing wrong, it all show up on one line?

Tags: java

My teacher asked that we create a table that is 10 columns across and shows the ASCII characters from 33 to 127.

I get the characters but they are all on one line.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ASCIICharacters {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
       char a,b=0;
       for (a=33;a<126+1;a++) {
           if(b%10==0) {
               System.out.print((Char)(a));
               System.out.print("   ");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never print new line...

Comment: Not printing any new lines.

Comment: Use `println` to print results each on a new line.

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.print()`

Comment: Along with the other comments,  `b` is never incremented in your code to make columns

Comment: You can add the variable definition/initialization to the `for` loop, too.

Comment: You should know that this works because the character set that Java (and JavaScript, and .NET, …) uses ([Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/)) is a superset of ASCII. So, "ASCII characters from 33 to 127" refers to those Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

A `newline` is never printed. You could do

```
for (char a = 33, b = 0; a < 127; a++, b++) {
    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.print("\t");

    if (b % 10 == 9) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also do `if (b % 10 == 9)`

Comment: yeah that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your code was using `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()` **and** you weren't incrementing the counter variable `b`, which is why the row-splitting wouldn't have worked, either.

Here's a solution that minimizes code duplication by avoiding the `System.out.print/ln` calls within the loop and instead storing the character values inside a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), value of which is then printed before the program exits:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 char c = 33;
 for (int i = 1; c <= 127; c++, i++) {
     sb.append(c);

     if (i % 10 == 0) {
         sb.append("\n"); // newline every 10th character
     } else {
         sb.append("   "); // else append with a separator
     }
 }
 System.out.println(sb);
```